# Can't get Buy Limit order set. My brains smoking now

Tags: pine-script, limit, program-entry-point

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// TraderHub

//@version=5
strategy('Bafitos', overlay = false , process_orders_on_close = true)
// Get user input
rsiLen      = input.int(title="RSI Length", defval=9)
rsiOB       = input.float(title="RSI Overbought", defval=80.0)
rsiOS       = input.float(title="RSI Oversold", defval=20.0)

// Price data on candle close or current price
price = close
rsi = ta.rsi(price, rsiLen)

// Draw signal lines on chart for signal visual test.
band1 = hline(rsiOS, 'Long', color=#08721f)
band0 = hline(rsiOB, 'Short', color=#f30b0b)

//  RSI Line  
plot(rsi, 'RSI', color=color.new(#969b96, 11))

// Signal lines for calculation of entry price (visual)

Longsignal = ta.crossover(rsi, rsiOS)
Shortsignal = ta.crossunder(rsi, rsiOB)
 
// Draw Lines green for a buy signal , red for a sell signal only for a visual test
bgcolor(Longsignal ? color.green : na)
bgcolor(Shortsignal ? color.red : na)

// Formula for entry Long position or Short position ( need to take % out of signal price for perfect limit order. % will set individualy for diferent ticker
percentTreshold = 0
confirm = true
purchasePrice = 0.0
buySignal = purchasePrice
testSignal = 0.0

// Entry price calculation logic
if (confirm)
    purchasePrice := close - (close * percentTreshold)
else
    purchasePrice := close + (close * percentTreshold)// not using yet .

//if close <= purchasePrice
  //testSignal := close

shouldPlaceOrder = purchasePrice// your enter condition
barsSincePlacingOrder = ta.barssince(shouldPlaceOrder)
shouldCancelOrder = barsSincePlacingOrder == 1 and strategy.position_size == 0

strategy.entry(limit = , strategy.long, quantity = 1, when = shouldPlaceOrder)
strategy.exit(id, loss = 10, profit = 20)
strategy.cancel(id, when = shouldCancelOrder)
```

Guys this is my first script. I guess im too old for this :) Please help me solve this Limit Order entry.I've been trading for 15 years but not coding. Thank You for your time.

Guys this is my first script. I guess im too old for this :) Please help me solve this Limit Order entry.I've been trading for 15 years but not coding. Thank You for your time.

Comment: What's the error that you see? What bug are you facing? Give more details. Show tracebacks, console output, how you tried to debug it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you should be aware of:

1. `strategy.entry()` function first parameter is `id`, which is a required parameter and the function won't work without it.
2. Once you use a parameter name, you'll need to use the parameter name for all the rest of the parameters.
3. The `id` parameter is a `string`, so you can't just write `id` as the parameter in the `strategy.exit()` function.
4. Your `limit` parameter in the `strategy.entry()` function is currently empty.
5. There is no `quantity` parameter in `strategy.entry()` function. It's called `qty`.
6. They stopped using the `when` parameter, so you'll need to use an `if` statement.

You can try, as a start, tweak the following:

```
if shouldPlaceOrder
    strategy.entry(id = "Enter Long", direction = strategy.long, limit = close, qty = 1)

strategy.exit(id = "Exit Long",from_entry = "Enter Long", loss = 10, profit = 20)
```

Comment: mr_statler Thank You for your Help.